# How to use phonegap plugin using eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins

After a long research and many attempts i couldn't able to use the phonegap/cordova plugins.
I want to use the camera (including video) plugin, image from gallery, voice recorder, notification and more. I was hoping somebody could explain me how to use these plugins or direct me to a good tutorial.
I was reading a lot in the official sites of cordova, phonegap and more and still- its not working.
(I'm using phonegap with eclipse).

Comment: You can use commandline tools to install cordova/phonegap plugins.You can check this (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)

Comment: what is the version of cordova?

Comment: update the version of cordova and you can add different plugins through commandline interface.

Comment: I tried to download the cordova commandline interface (node.js) and it didn't work. How do i check what is the version of cordova. @Dino

Comment: To check the version, use the command `cordova -version`

Comment: whats the command prompt error when you try to install a plugin ?